# Why does Pylint want two public methods per class?

Tags: python, pylint

I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027417/what-does-pylints-too-few-public-methods-message-mean) why the warning exists. However, why would the default value of it be 2?

It seems to me that classes with a single public method aside from `__init__` are perfectly normal! Is there any caveat to just setting

```
min-public-methods=1
```

in the pylintrc file?

Comment: No. Also, if you google for `"min-public-methods"`, you'd find many `pylintrc`s that use this or even 0.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking - the linked question tells you why that rule exists, so if you disagree with that or it doesn't apply, feel free to ignore it!

Comment: The question is, why did the pylint developers choose 2 as the default value instead of 1. Let me know if you still think the original question is not clear.

Answer (score 12):

The number 2 is completely arbitrary. If `min-public-methods=1` is a more fitting policy for your project and better matches your code esthetic opinions, then by all means go for it. As [was once said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14027686/3809977), "Pylint doesn't know what's best".

Answer (score 1):

For another perspective, Jack Diederich gave a talk at PyCon 2012 called "[Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)".

One of his examples is the class with a single method, which he suggests should be just a function. If the idea is to set up an object containing a load of data and a single method that can be called later (perhaps many times) to act on that data, then you can still do that with a regular function by making an inner function the return value.

Something like:

```
def complicated(a, b, c, d, e):
    def inner(k):
       return (a*k, b*k, c*k, d*k, e*k)
    return inner
foo = complicated(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
result = foo(100)
```

This does seem much simpler to me than:

```
class Complicated:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e

    def calc(self, k)
        return (self.a*k, self.b*k, self.c*k, self.d*k, self.e*k)

foo = Complicated(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
result = Complicated.calc(100)
```

The main limitation of the function based approach is that you cannot read back the values of a, b, c, d, and e in the example.

Comment: IDK if this is still true today now that we have dataclasses.

Comment: @JoshuaJones A dataclass would only remove the need for the `__init__` method. And in most 'real life' cases part of the reason for this kind of thing (not shown in my example) is that you pre-calculate a load of stuff when you set the object up. So using a dataclass you'd probably end up having to define a `__post_init__` method and you are back to square one. The beauty of the inner function approach is its simplicity and economy.

Comment: Saying the first options is much simpler is very subjective. I'd argue the second option allows me to read the function in blocks (initialization vs. execution).

Of course, for such toy examples, it's hard to see it, but if your `__init__` sets up anything serious, it immediately becomes clear. And if execution requires several steps and depends on other objects, it would be madness to pack it all into a single function, but a class with a single public method and multiple private methods would be easily more readable

Comment: @Neowizard There's nothing to stop you splitting the initialisation into multiple inner functions. We've all been conditioned into thinking classes are the [golden hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument). That might be true in some languages, but not Python.

Comment: @IanGoldby I think 3 level of function nesting before we consider the nesting for logic/control flow isn't the right solution. At this point, it would feel to me (as a reader/reviewer) that the coder was actively avoiding making a class, and I'd start to try and figure out whether there was an actual reason for this, distracting me further from the actual code.

Comment: For people who come from strongly typed languages and are thus not used to such magic that's pretty much only possible in python (and maybe JS), the second solution is way more readable...

Comment: @AlexGeorg Perhaps, but if you take that approach seriously then you would avoid any Python feature that doesn't exist in other languages because devs coming from other languages would not find it readable. So then why use Python at all? Python code is supposed to look like Python, not C#.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the "[Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)" answer, let's consider the situation in old-school JavaScript for a moment.

Here's a [page suggesting few patterns for pre-es6 JavaScript](https://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) (before it added classes) and here's one more discussed in Q: [Understanding Crockford's classless OOP implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615655/understanding-crockfords-classless-oop-implementation).

The main thing that classes give us is an easily (statically) discoverable type hierarchy, which is helpful when you are using various tooling (IDEs, autocompletion).

> The venerable master Qc Na was walking with his student, Anton.  Hoping to
> prompt the master into a discussion, Anton said "Master, I have heard that
> objects are a very good thing - is this true?"  Qc Na looked pityingly at
> his student and replied, "Foolish pupil - objects are merely a poor man's
> closures."
>
> Chastised, Anton took his leave from his master and returned to his cell,
> intent on studying closures.  He carefully read the entire "Lambda: The
> Ultimate..." series of papers and its cousins, and implemented a small
> Scheme interpreter with a closure-based object system.  He learned much, and
> looked forward to informing his master of his progress.
>
> On his next walk with Qc Na, Anton attempted to impress his master by
> saying "Master, I have diligently studied the matter, and now understand
> that objects are truly a poor man's closures."  Qc Na responded by hitting
> Anton with his stick, saying "When will you learn? Closures are a poor man's
> object."  At that moment, Anton became enlightened.
>
> from https://people.csail.mit.edu/gregs/ll1-discuss-archive-html/msg03277.html

See ["Closures are poor man's objects and vice versa" - What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497801/closures-are-poor-mans-objects-and-vice-versa-what-does-this-mean)