# SQLAlchemy and pylint

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylint

SQLAlchemy seems to give me a ton of errors on pylint that I can't resolve.

The first problem is that each table must be defined as a new class.

Example:

```
class Person(BASE):
    """Person Table Definition"""
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(30))
```

...causes these errors ***for each table*** I define:

```
W: 20, 0: Class has no __init__ method (no-init)
R: 20, 0: Too few public methods (0/2) (too-few-public-methods)
```

The second problem is using a global variable for the SQLAlchemy `engine` and `BASE` constructs. I'm not sure how I can refactor this code to make these variables not global, since the parameter `BASE` must be passed into the table class definitions above.

```
BASE = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
global engine
...
def create_sqla_engine():
    """Create the SQLA engine"""
    global engine
    engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/sqlalchemy_example')
```

I'm new to python but this seems ugly. pylint complains about it, too:

```
C: 51, 0: Invalid constant name "engine" (invalid-name)
```

Finally, pylint thinks I'm not using the imports that I am clearly using in this code.

```
W: 15, 0: Unused declarative_base imported from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative (unused-import)
W: 16, 0: Unused sessionmaker imported from sqlalchemy.orm (unused-import)
```

...why? Is pylint not compatible with python3? Should I be importing the modules I need within the methods they are used, instead of at the top of the file?

Comment: While `BASE` should not cause any problems, `global engine` is indeed a code smell. Learn how to return an engine instance form a method. You only need to work with engine sparingly; you should mostly be requesting sessions from `sessionmaker`, which is cheap.

Comment: WRT 'no init' and 'too few public methods' for classes that have a metaclass, like tables, there is [an open bug](http://www.logilab.org/ticket/33636).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is not very pylint-friendly.

There are a few things in your question.

## 1. Too few public methods

This error is often wrong, see here: [What does pylint's "Too few public methods" message mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027417/what-does-pylints-too-few-public-methods-message-mean/)

## 2. Unused imports

Pylint is right in this case! If you import `declarative_base`, you can use it directly: `declarative_base(...)`, and not via `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()`.

Generally - if an import is unused, try to remove it and check if your code (and unit tests, watch out for doctests!) still works. If so, the import was indeed unused.

TL;DR - yes, you're using the **code**, but not using the imported **names**.

## 3. Invalid constant name

Pylint is wrong in this instance, but somewhat right in principle.

(I spent many hours convincing even decent programmers to just override Pylint's `const-rgx` setting...).

Basically, Pylint believes every global variable is a constant. In your case it's not. So, pylint tries to discourage you from using global variables.

Also, you shouldn't write `global engine` outside of the functions (at global scope). It should be something like:

`engine = None`

Pylint will still complain about wrong constant name. You can silence this warning explicitly. (I don't recommend renaming it to `ENGINE`)

## 4. (extra) SQLAlchemy query building

I found this question, because I wanted to see something about pylint's suggestion in SQLAlchemy conditions.

Unlike Django models, SQLAlchemy uses comparisons `==` to have an equality condition (Django's `field_gt=5` is actually clumsy, I've got to liking SQLAlchemy's way over time). But Pylint will complain:

```
session.query(AlarmState).filter(AlarmState.is_default == True).one()
```

gives

```
C0121: comparison to True should be just 'expr' or 'expr is True'
```

It's all good and well - in this case we can really write:

```
session.query(AlarmState).filter(AlarmState.is_default).one()
```

And it's fine.

But, what about:

```
session.query(AlarmState).filter(AlarmState.is_default == False).all()
```

well, we get:

```
C0121: comparison to False should be just 'not expr' or 'expr is False'
```

What now? This doesn't work: `session.query(AlarmState).filter(not AlarmState.is_default .all()`!!! - it seems to filter by a `False` condition, and returns an empty set. Same here: `sess.query(AlarmState).filter(AlarmState.is_default is False).all()`.

I have found a way around it - you actually can write:

```
session.query(AlarmState).filter(AlarmState.is_default.__eq__(False)).all()
```

And it both:

- gives correct result
- doesn't raise the Pylint notice

I just don't feel great about this. It's playing cat and mouse with this stupid tool.
I was wondering about what others do about it, and that's how I got here.

**EDIT** - ok, I found the "right" way to do it...

### How to compare column to `False` (without complaints)?

```
from sqlalchemy import not_
session.query(AlarmState).filter(not_(AlarmState.is_default)).all()
```

This is what `not_` is probably for...

Comment: Sometimes that's a perfect use of `not_` although I prefer the more readable `session.query(AlarmState).filter(AlarmState.is_default.is_(False)).all()`. It also works nicely with not doing equality comparisons on True/False values.

Comment: But what to do with `too few public methods`? I mean, this question isn't answered for SQLAlchemy

Comment: Short answer: switch  to `flake8`. Pylance (used in VS Code) is also OK. Alternatives: turn off this rule in your pylint config. It's a bad rule anyway.